# Line parallel to the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given plane with equation: $4mx+(m−1)y−(m−4)z=−2m−2$. Find m so that line with vector $(4,4,1)$ will be parallel.

Now I tried $a*n=0$ and that gave me $-21m=-2$ so in that case solution would be $m=\frac{2}{21}$ but right solution is $m=0$. So what is correct procedure to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reconstruct how you got $m=\tfrac{2}{21}$, but did you take the (red) minus sign into account?

> $4mx+(m−1)y\color{red}{−}(m−4)z=−2m−2$

Because with $\color{red}{−}(m−4) = \color{blue}{4-m}$, that gives:

$$(4m,m-1,\color{blue}{4-m})\cdot(4,4,1) = 0 \iff 19m = 0 \iff m = 0$$

Comment: So where do I move $−2m−2$? I got 21 by moving -2m to other side and adding 19m so that resulted into 21. Or can I just ignore right side and turn it into 0 ?

Comment: You don't need the right-hand side because it doesn't influence the orientation of the plane. You only need the plane's normal vector (and get that to be perpendicular to the line's direction vector).